# belongs_to not making join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have users table with:

- id
- username

and questions table with

- id
- asker_id
- question_text

So when I need to get a question from db I need the username too.

So I made:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :question_text, presence: true
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "asker_id"
end

#controller
def index
    @questions = Question.order(id: 'desc')
end

#view
<strong><%= question.user.username %>:</strong>
<%= question.question_text %> at 
<i><%= question.created_at %></i>
```

I was expecting that questions to make join to users but in console I see:

```
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"  ORDER BY "questions"."id" DESC
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

How do I get a join?

Comment: You need to use either `joins` or `includes`. Have a look at these [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can used like

```
@questions = Question.includes(:user).order(id: 'desc')
```

so if you want to access username for particular question you can directly get it by

```
@questions.first.user.username
```